# MVC3 - How to get the controller's physical path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, path, controller

Does anyone know how to get the physical path inside a controller (e.g. HomeController.cs)?

I tried `HttpContext.Request.PhysicalPath` in Index() but it returns

```
"C:\My Projects\MyMVCProject\MvcApplication1"
```

instead of the following (which is what I need):

```
"C:\My Projects\MyMVCProject\MvcApplication1\Controllers\HomeController.cs"
```

Thanks.

Comment: brian, as an alternative angle, what is it that you want to use this info for as there may be another solution based on your full requirement ?? my gut feel is saying that you're looking at T4 scaffolding

Comment: Thanks Jim.  For better grouping, I add a few sub-folders under the main 'Controllers' folder (such as Home, Menu1, Menu2 ... etc).  My HomeController.cs is actually in the 'Home' sub-folder instead of sitting directly under the main 'Controllers' folder.  There will be a few more controllers in each of these sub-folders (eg. submenu1_1, submenu1_2, submenu1_3... etc).  I like to use the above approach to figure out the name of the corresponding sub-folder for each controller, so I can assign the 'selected' css class to the particular menu item to highlight it as selected on the website.

Comment: I am extremely new to MVC.  I am not sure if this is a proper approach or it doesn't make sense at all.  I am looking for a proper way to 'structure' the controller in a site with main menu and sub menus.  I have posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434003/mvc3-best-practice-for-site-with-main-menu-and-sub-menu.  Please help.

Comment: I think what you are doing is not a great plan, you can structure your application in the way you are describing using Areas.  Also I would name your controllers after a logical group of application / domain functions.  I am not sure Menu1 and Menu2 would be my idea of good controllers.